# Passing arguments and variables from a decorator to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm new with decorators so sorry if this seems obvious.

I have a decorator called Test_Decorator. From argument 1 and 2, it's going to output a list.

```
def Test_Decorator(argument1, argument2):

   def Test(AnotherFunc):

      def Wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

          """
          Do stuff with argument1 and 2
          Output List
          """

           List=["List", "Here"]

           return AnotherFunc(*args, **kwargs)

      return Wrapper

  return Test
```

Now, I want to use that decorator on Func2.

This function is supposed to use the list from the decorator, the 2 arguments from the decorator, and 2 new arguments (argument 3 and 4).

```
@Test_Decorator(argument1, argument2)
def Func2(List, argument3, argument4):

   for i in List:
       """
       Do stuff with argument 1 to 4 and with List
       """
```

The problem is that Func2 can't use argument1, argument2 and List. I'm stuck here, can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you pass `List1` to `AnotherFunc(*args, **kwargs)`? something like `AnotherFunct(List1=List1, argument3=argument1, argument4=argument2)`

Comment: But I can't do that, because argument1 and 2 aren't the same as argument3 and 4